# Find distinct column id and column count with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table bookorder_t with columns as follows
orderid,bookid, ordersuccess . I want to find the all bookids where ordersuccess= 1,
and count of book ids.

Suppose this is my bookorder_t

```
orderid bookid  ordersuccess
----------------------------
100      1         1
101      1         null
102      1         1
103      2         1
104      2         1
106      1         1
```

My expected result is

```
bookid count
1       3
2       2
```

How to write query for this in in linq?

Comment: Not tested but the following should do it. `context.bookorder_t.Where(x => x.ordersuccess == 1).GroupBy(x => x.bookid).Select(g => new { bookid = g.Key, count = g.Count() })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the correct result:-

```
var result = db.bookorder_t.Where(x => x.ordersuccess == 1)
                           .GroupBy(x => x.bookid)
                           .Select(x => new 
                                      {
                                           bookid  = x.Key,
                                           count = x.Count()
                                      });
```

Comment: brilliant and simple.. thanks. it worked for me.Thank you so much.

Comment: atually in my table one more column is there with name bookstoreid.
I need to find the selected bookstore's all books whose order is success (that is ordersuccess = 1)
both bookstoreid and bookid are foreign keys.  So How can I get the bookname also in the result.?

bookstore_t columns : bookstorename,bookstoreid,
book_t columns      : bookid,bookname,bookstoreid,
bookorder_t columns : orderid,bookid,bookstoreid,ordersuccess

Comment: @BhavinBhaskaran - You can include other column also in `GroupBy` like this : `GroupBy(x => new { x.bookid, x.bookname }).Select(x => new { bookname = x.Key.bookname, bookid = x.Key.bookid,...}`

Comment: It also worked. Thank you so much. Can you provide some good links to learn linq.It will be a great help.

Comment: @BhavinBhaskaran -You're Welcome:) You can start from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx and after reading the concepts practice the samples from here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thanks again. and last one more doubt. If I  have bookid 1,2,3,4...10 in my book_T table but in bookorder_t only 1,2 the out put will display count of 1, and 2.. but if i need to display all bookid from 1...10 (even though count will be zero) how can i do it? good if you can reply.

Comment: @BhavinBhaskaran - I guess you have two tables there. You can apply left join using `DefaultIfEmpty`. Search for it you can find many examples for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91234/discussion-between-bhavin-bhaskaran-and-rahul-singh).